# Android+Eclipse: How to clean/reset an AVD

Tags: android, eclipse

Is there a way to 'clean' an AVD?

Can I only delete and re-create it?

This question is because I'm developing a custom layout for a `ListView` and I can't see the update I'm applying.

I tried to uninstall the application, too, to clean and re-run it unsuccessfully.

Answer (score 8):

When you start an AVD there is an option to "wipe user data". That option will remove any user installed apps.

Comment: Done as you said, tried more and more with no success. Only `mvn clean` on command line has worked. Anyway, many thanks :)